# Create a running total of a list of numbers in awk?

Tags: awk

I need to sum numbers like this

Input `1 5 6 8 9 11`

Output `1 6 12 20 29 40`

That is:
1 1+5 1+5+6 1+5+6+8 1+5+6+8+9 1+5+6+8+9+11

Comment: That is not the sum of consecutive numbers. I Think it may be called a running total.

Comment: this help so much

Comment: something like this i dont find the answer befor because i dont know the called of this process http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567142/awk-running-total-count-and-sum

Comment: @VictorHernandez: It'a simple task. You can do it!

Comment: @FloHe Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I think it would be educationally better for him to solve it himself, as this is a good self-teaching task for awk beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`:

```
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", s += $i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The loop goes over all input fields and prints the running total (`s`) of the numbers. The variable `s` doesn't need to be initialized as its value will taken as zero on the first iteration.  The result of the assignment to `s` is the value of `s`, which is then printed with a trailing space character.

With the example input:

```
$ echo "1 5 6 8 9 11" | awk -f script.awk
1 6 12 20 29 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using the "dc" calculator command:

```
echo '1 5 6 8 9 11' |
dc -e "
[SM]sa               # macro a pushes TOS into stack M              
[dn32and]sp          # macro p prints current sum value
[z 1 <a SM z 0 <b]sb # macro b accumulates the main stack in stack M
[LM+lpx z lN !<c]sc  # macro c is while loop for showing running sum
? zsN lbx 0 lcx []p  # main() which brings together all macros
"
```

Comment: This looks like an overkill :). But if it works, why not...

Comment: But wait, in my bash I'm getting a syntax error: `> [LM+lpx z lN !<c]sc  # macro c is while loop for showing running sum
bash: !: event not found`

Comment: Escape the bang (\!) to suppress history mechanism from kicking in. What bash version is running at your end as I don't see this error (bash 4.3.39)

Comment: I use `GNU bash, version 4.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)` and after escaping the `!` I get the errors: `dc: 1 '\' (0134) unimplemented
dc: 6 '\' (0134) unimplemented
dc: 12 '\' (0134) unimplemented
dc: 20 '\' (0134) unimplemented
dc: 29 '\' (0134) unimplemented
dc: 40 '\' (0134) unimplemented
`

Comment: Then in that case we can do away with the ! and construct it differently  as: `[LM+lpx z lN1+ >c]sc  # macro c is while loop....`

Comment: Never mind! Your solution looks interesting and if it works on some shells it's fine.